# Red Hat Linux - Publicly available CIFS mount

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, server-message-block

I have mounted a Windows file system on a Dell server running RHEL 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5 using a software called Sharity. The filesystem is accessible just fine to the userid that ran the mount command but to no one else (Permission Denied)

Is there a way to make the mounted filesystem available (readonly) to other users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the parameters in your fstab:

```
uid=(Linux User Owner for Permissions)
gid=(Linux Group for Permissions)
file_mode=744 - for group and public readonly
file_mode=740 - for group readonly
dir_mode=744 - for group and public readonly
dir_mode=740 - for group readonly
```

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: Sorry, I just clarified that the mount is done using a software called Sharity. That seems to maintain state in its own files instead of fstab. Any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: http://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=90&p=224

OK I found the answer to my question on the product forum, should have looked there first before posting on serverfault. Sorry.